# How do I connect two RFID readers at the same time to my Arduino?

Tags: arduino, soldering, rfid, arduino-uno, ide

I’m making a simple door lock for my room using an Arduino uno and an RFID sensor, I made the code to unlock the door with the correct tag, but it’s only on one side, I need a way to unlock the door from the other side as well, could I connect another sensor to the same pins on the Arduino since only one would be used at a time?[image: can I attach another sensor to the exact same pins?]

Comment: it may be illegal to have a door locked from both sides where you live

Comment: @jsotola It would be lockable from both sides and unlockable from both sides easily there will be a emergency open button that will trip an alarm but allow you to escape, it’s mostly to just keep my brother out of my room without me knowing

Comment: Well if it's to keep your brother out why would you need RFID to get out rather than a door release button - unless you want to lock your brother in the room (if he does manage to get in) until you get home?

Comment: It’s not a sensor, it’s a RFID reader. Assuming you’re using SPI mode, you can connect another but the select signal has to connect to another gpio and you run another instance of the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to same pins? Maybe for DC power supply, but not for signals except in the special case where such connection is made possible by design including both hardware and software. Impossible to say is your case such lucky one because we have no circuit nor software details.

Seriously: Think your idea a second time. Start by imagining that there's a fire and you are rushing out, because the flames are already licking your back. I'm sure you want there's a mechanical way to open the door.

Comment: I have a huge glass door that I can use as an escape in case something happens and it leads out onto a field of grass that is not dry so it won’t really burn and I can escape to safety, anyway, if connecting to the same pins won’t work, then how can I make it work? Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @ComputerNoob It's already said in a comment (by Kartman). Use other I/O pins for data to and from the other reader. And modify the software so that both readers get attention. How to do these? Only who knows the hardware and software details can answer. I guess it would be a miracle if someone here happens to have just the same system as you and also the needed documents + knowledge. Sorry.